# How do I hide Admin link in master page until user logs in?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

In our master page, we are trying to hide the link to Admin screen on page load. Here is the code:

```
<div class="footer" id="divAdmin" Visible="False">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="~/admin.aspx">Administration Page</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

After the user successfully logs in, show the link if the user is an admin. An admin has userRole of 1 assigned to it.

I am trying to accomplish this with code below on page_load() event:

```
If Session("UserRole") = 1 Then
 divAdmin.Visible = True
End If
```

I can't get beyond the error the following error:

> Error  'divAdmin' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Visible` to `False` in markup. Add `runat="server"` to the element. Set `Visible` to `True` in code-behind once authenticated.

```
<div class="footer" id="divAdmin" Visible="False" runat="server">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="~/admin.aspx">Administration Page</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


If Session("UserRole") = 1 Then
 divAdmin.Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: That's exactly the way my code is written. As stated, I cannot get beyond the error that `divAdmin is not declared`

Comment: You don't have runat="server". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11510589/397817 for more info.

Comment: This link may be more helpful. See the section "ASP.NET - HTML Server Controls". http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_controls.asp

Comment: Sorry about that @Stephen. I must have mistakenly taken the runat="server" out just trying and pasting from one section of the master page to another hoping to get it to work. Right now though, the error is gone but is still doesn't show the link after successful login and I have a userRole of 1.

Ok, I see it now. I had to add Handles Me.Load to page_load() event.

Thank you for your prompt assistance.