# runat="server" effect in head section of the page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am defining variable css files in head section on my pages (different skins) but can't define them when head has runat="server" (that is there by default) as `<%%>` is not allowed in runat="server" sections removing runat="server" solves the problem but what is the differece (effect) of having this attribute or not in the head section:

```
<head>
<title> some title </title>
<link href="<%=skin_common%>.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<%=skin_color%>.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason the runat attribute is needed in the head section is if your server-side code needs to access it. Outside of that, you can safely remove it.

Comment: @rishChieftain what do you mean by accessing it? like setting title dynamically?

Comment: Yes, for that my understanding is that you WOULD need runat. Some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510502/understanding-the-runat-server-attribute

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/specifying-the-title-meta-tags-and-other-html-headers-in-the-master-page-vb

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to remove `runat="server"` if you use `Title` directive of `@Page` or set `Page.Title` in codebehind.