# Enable click button when a radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a list of radio buttons generated dynamically by a list view. The user selects one radio button and click the Update button to update his data. I want to keep the button disabled until the user makes his selection. How can I accomplish that?

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID_BG" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_BGlist">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <itemtemplate>                
            <label><input id="Radio1" name="BG_list" type="radio" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>'/>
                <img alt="" style="width:150px" src="/Members/images/BG/icons/<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>"></label>                 
        </itemtemplate> ....



    <asp:Button disabled="disabled" CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Change" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to change your Background Image?');" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao Gloria,

You should add jQuery and then this piece of code in the header:

```
$(function () {
  $("input[id*='Radio1']").click(function () {
    $("#<%=UpdateButton.ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled');
  });
});
```

To have ASP.NET supplanting `<%=UpdateButton.ClientID %>` with the actual ID of the control, you must enable the head as a server-side control, because ASP.NET will otherwise not check the content of `<head>` neither nested `<script>` tags:

```
<head runat="server">
  <script>

    // server-side variant JS with ASP.NET <%= tags %>

  </script>
</head>
```

More about this topic here: [Understanding the runat server attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510502/understanding-the-runat-server-attribute)

Comment: I'm getting this error on Debug....The name 'UpdateButton' does not exist in the current context.... It's obvious that the script can't find the button, maybe cause it's inside a FormView?

Comment: Ah, ok, yes. Nesting controls causes these problems. Use: `FormView1.FindControl("UpdateButton").ClientID`.

Comment: Thank you all....Now it works. Is there any drawback for this function, especially on mobiles? Never tested it before.

Comment: I don't think there are any drawbacks, you're golden :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: bind `change` event to radio button using `.on()` as radio buttons generated dynamically and enable update button inside it.

```
$(function(){
 $(document).on('change','input[name="BG_list"]',function(){
    $('#UpdateButton').removeAttr('disabled');
 });
});
```

**EDIT** - use update button id like `$("#<%=UpdateButton.ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled');` as mentioned in @pid answer. As I am not asp.net developer so don't know about this that actual id could be different.

Comment: Thanks but the script doesn't find the button as explained above