# After calling view by form post method view design is changed in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, partial-views

I am getting one issue in MVC project that when I load the page at that time view design is perfect but after the click event time when I called the same view at that time it changed the design.

I used one partial view, one view and one controller.

Now when call the index event at load event time the theme of website showing perfect. Here is the image:

[image: Website theme]

Here is my controller code of index event:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var getYear = db.yearMaster.OrderBy(y => y.Year).ToList();
                SelectList yearList = new SelectList(getYear, "YearID", "Year");
                ViewBag.YearListName = yearList;

                var getEvent = db.eventMaster.OrderBy(y => y.Event).ToList();
                SelectList eventList = new SelectList(getEvent, "EventID", "Event");
                ViewBag.EventListName = eventList;

                var getBranch = db.branch.OrderBy(y => y.Branch).ToList();
                SelectList branchList = new SelectList(getBranch, "BranchID", "Branch");
                ViewBag.BranchListName = branchList;

                var content = db.eventRegistration.Select(s => new
                {
                    s.EventRegistrationID,
                    s.Image,
                    s.IsActive
                }).Where(c => c.IsActive == true).Take(15).ToList();

                List<EventRegistrationViewModel> contentModel = content.Select(item => new EventRegistrationViewModel()
                {
                    EventRegistrationID = item.EventRegistrationID,
                    Image = item.Image,
                    IsActive = item.IsActive
                }).ToList();

                return View(contentModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Here is the view named `index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<SchoolWebApplication.ViewModel.EventRegistrationViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PublicLayout.cshtml";
}

@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>*@
<script src="~/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<link href="~/Context/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="~/js/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
      $("#ShowImage").fancybox({
          helpers:
          {
              title:
              {
                type: 'float'
             }
          }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .imgBox 
   {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        opacity: 1.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    }
   .imgBox:hover
   {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
         box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
         opacity: 0.4;
         filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   }

</style>
@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterImage", "Glimpses", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#YearList").change(function () {
                $("#yearID").val($(this).val()); 
            });

            $("#eventList").change(function () {
                $("#eventID").val($(this).val());
            });

            $("#branchList").change(function () {
                $("#branchID").val($(this).val());
            });

        });
    </script>

    <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left: 38px; width:149px">
                        @Html.DropDownList("YearList", ViewBag.YearListName as SelectList, "Select Year")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DropDownList("eventList", ViewBag.EventListName as SelectList, "Select Event")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        @Html.DropDownList("branchList", ViewBag.BranchListName as SelectList, "Select Branch")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="submit" value="Get Image" id="btn_searchimage" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </legend>
        </fieldset>
    <div style="height:600px; margin-left: 25px;">
        <div style="border-bottom:1px solid Red;"></div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span2">
                 <div class="item">
                   @foreach (var item in Model)
                   {
                       <script>
                           alert();
                       </script>
                     <div style=" margin:10px; float:left; height:200px; overflow:hidden; width:200px;">
                       <a id="ShowImage" class="fancybox-button" data-rel="fancybox-button" 
                           href="#">
                         <div class="zoom">
                             <img src='/Glimpses/RetrieveEventImage/@item.EventRegistrationID' alt="No Image" class="imgBox"/>
                              <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
                         </div>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                   }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now, up to this there is no problem but if I filter the data as seen in image and call the view, at that time the design is changed.

Here is the image of the changed image:

[image: Distorted website]

Here is the `filterimage` event code in the same controller:

```
public ActionResult FilterImage(EventRegistrationViewModel eventRegistrationViewModel, int yearList, int eventList, int branchList) //
{
    try
    {
        var getYear = db.yearMaster.OrderBy(y => y.Year).ToList();
        SelectList abc = new SelectList(getYear, "YearID", "Year");
        ViewBag.YearListName = abc;

        var getEvent = db.eventMaster.OrderBy(y => y.Event).ToList();
        SelectList def = new SelectList(getEvent, "EventID", "Event");
        ViewBag.EventListName = def;

        var getBranch = db.branch.OrderBy(y => y.Branch).ToList();
        SelectList ijk = new SelectList(getBranch, "BranchID", "Branch");
        ViewBag.BranchListName = ijk;

        var content = db.eventRegistration.Select(s => new
        {
            s.EventRegistrationID,
            s.EventID,
            s.Image,
            s.IsActive,
            s.YearID,
            s.BranchID
        }).Where(c => c.IsActive == true && c.YearID == yearList && c.BranchID == branchList && c.EventID == eventList).ToList();

        List<EventRegistrationViewModel> contentModel = content.Select(item => new EventRegistrationViewModel()
        {
            EventRegistrationID = item.EventRegistrationID,
            Image = item.Image,
            IsActive = item.IsActive,
            YearID = yearList,
            BranchID = branchList
        }).ToList();

        return View("index",contentModel);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure there is no exception at `FilterImage`.

Comment: sorry....I am not getting?

Comment: Debug your `FilterImage` action and  make sure the code executes without throwing any exception. Add break point in your  `catch` block.

Comment: Yah I debug and the code excutes perfectly without any error.

Comment: does your partial view have css styles in it.

Comment: @Saineshwar Yes, my partial view containing css file path

Comment: just comment and try once

Comment: @Saineshwar but if I comment that css path then my website theme is not perfect at once also.

Comment: but your css must be on Main layout page right why it is in partial view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the problem is with this type of linking scripts and css. Try to resolve your url on server using this:

```
<%=ResolveUrl("~/path/file.js")
```

Like this:

```
<script src="<%=this.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js")%>"></script>
```

Comment: I dont think so that there is problem with the path because if it problem with the path then at that first also design view is not want to shown clear but it is showing clear.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510502/understanding-the-runat-server-attribute/16729311#16729311. In design view it may work but while running page url probably aren'r resolved.

Comment: thank you for giving me such a reference link. But that link also didnt work.

Comment: can You check if your css and js files are linked correctly on this corrupted view?

Comment: I got the solution there is a incorrect url of css path. Thank You. :)