# Navbar not collapsing in asp.NET webform

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm doing an ASP.NET web page which includes a navbar using bootstrap 4.
When the screen is small I got the toggle button to appear, but when I click it nothing happens, it looks like it tries to show the menu options, but nothing happens.
The navber is inside the form tag, everything works fine if I put the navbar outside the form tag.

Can anyone tell me what's happening here, I have no clue now, thanks

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Inicio</title>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/Custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Title</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item float-right"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Register</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">LogIn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav> 

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing to link your JavaScript libaries correctly at the top. Please check this.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Live link: 
https://codepen.io/tayyabrana101/pen/VwwPmLO

Comment: thanks but still not working, it works fine when it's just html but when I out the navbar code inside <form id="form1" runat="server"> </form> the toggle functionality stops working

Comment: yes, because <form> is letting toggler to hyperlink to OnPost route, which is overriding the default id link which to open the menu when screen is small.

Comment: I think by using "runat=Server" attribute you are changing stylesheet path. I just heard from this answer. The one answer by @xypho https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510502/understanding-the-runat-server-attribute